# RoR Michael Hartl Tutorial (3rd) - An error occurred while installing sqlite3, and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sqlite, cloud9-ide

Others have asked a similar questions before but none have been using the cloud9 IDE. I have tried solutions to other questions, but still can't get it to work.

I am doing the Michael Hartl Ruby on Rails Tutorial (3rd) and using the cloud9 IDE (as I run Windows OS).

When I try to push my master branch from Bitbucket to Heroku.

```
$ git push heroku master
```

I get the error:

```
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler cannot continue.
```

I appreciate that Heroku does not support sqlite. But I have followed the tutorial very closely. And I can't see where I have gone wrong.

Here is the full code:

```
kpscowley:~/workspace/hello_app2 (master) $ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 66, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (55/55), done.
Writing objects: 100% (66/66), 16.75 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 66 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.9.7
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path             vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Rubygems 2.0.14.1 is not threadsafe, so your gems must be     installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel     gem installation.
remote:        Installing rake 10.4.2
remote:        Installing i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Installing json 1.8.3
remote:        Installing minitest 5.8.3
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Installing activesupport 4.2.2
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.2
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing mini_portile2 2.0.0
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.6.7.1
remote:        Installing rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Installing rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
remote:        Installing loofah 2.0.3
remote:        Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
remote:        Installing actionview 4.2.2
remote:        Installing rack 1.6.4
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing actionpack 4.2.2
remote:        Installing globalid 0.3.6
remote:        Installing activejob 4.2.2
remote:        Installing mime-types 2.99
remote:        Installing mail 2.6.3
remote:        Installing actionmailer 4.2.2
remote:        Installing activemodel 4.2.2
remote:        Installing arel 6.0.3
remote:        Installing activerecord 4.2.2
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.10.0
remote:        Installing execjs 2.6.0
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing thor 0.19.1
remote:        Installing railties 4.2.2
remote:        Installing coffee-rails 4.1.1
remote:        Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.0
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.11.2
remote:        Installing jbuilder 2.3.2
remote:        Installing jquery-rails 4.0.5
remote:        Using bundler 1.9.7
remote:        Installing sprockets 3.5.2
remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 3.0.0
remote:        Installing rails 4.2.2
remote:        Installing rdoc 4.2.1
remote:        Installing sass 3.4.20
remote:        Installing tilt 2.0.1
remote:        Installing sass-rails 5.0.4
remote:        Installing sdoc 0.4.1
remote:        Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:        /tmp/build_287067056d8f395e2b2b5684ca54eff3/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:        --with-opt-dir
remote:        --without-opt-dir
remote:        --with-opt-include
remote:        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:        --with-opt-lib
remote:        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:        --with-make-prog
remote:        --without-make-prog
remote:        --srcdir=.
remote:        --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_287067056d8f395e2b2b5684ca54eff3/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby
remote:        --with-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --without-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --with-sqlite3-include
remote:        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
remote:        --with-sqlite3-lib
remote:        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_287067056d8f395e2b2b5684ca54eff3/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11 for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to /tmp/build_287067056d8f395e2b2b5684ca54eff3/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:        Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Rubygems 2.0.14.1 is not threadsafe, so your gems must be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
remote:        Installing rake 10.4.2
remote:        Installing i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Installing json 1.8.3
remote:        Installing minitest 5.8.3
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Installing activesupport 4.2.2
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.2
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing mini_portile2 2.0.0
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.6.7.1
remote:        Installing rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Installing rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
remote:        Installing loofah 2.0.3
remote:        Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
remote:        Installing actionview 4.2.2
remote:        Installing rack 1.6.4
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing actionpack 4.2.2
remote:        Installing globalid 0.3.6
remote:        Installing activejob 4.2.2
remote:        Installing mime-types 2.99
remote:        Installing mail 2.6.3
remote:        Installing actionmailer 4.2.2
remote:        Installing activemodel 4.2.2
remote:        Installing arel 6.0.3
remote:        Installing activerecord 4.2.2
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.10.0
remote:        Installing execjs 2.6.0
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing thor 0.19.1
remote:        Installing railties 4.2.2
remote:        Installing coffee-rails 4.1.1
remote:        Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.0
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.11.2
remote:        Installing jbuilder 2.3.2
remote:        Installing jquery-rails 4.0.5
remote:        Using bundler 1.9.7
remote:        Installing sprockets 3.5.2
remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 3.0.0
remote:        Installing rails 4.2.2
remote:        Installing rdoc 4.2.1
remote:        Installing sass 3.4.20
remote:        Installing tilt 2.0.1
remote:        Installing sass-rails 5.0.4
remote:        Installing sdoc 0.4.1
remote:        
remote:        Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:        
remote:        /tmp/build_287067056d8f395e2b2b5684ca54eff3/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:        
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:        --with-opt-dir
remote:        --without-opt-dir
remote:        --with-opt-include
remote:        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:        --with-opt-lib
remote:        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:        --with-make-prog
remote:        --without-make-prog
remote:        --srcdir=.
remote:        --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_287067056d8f395e2b2b5684ca54eff3/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby
remote:        --with-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --without-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --with-sqlite3-include
remote:        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
remote:        --with-sqlite3-lib
remote:        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_287067056d8f395e2b2b5684ca54eff3/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11 for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to /tmp/build_287067056d8f395e2b2b5684ca54eff3/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to powerful-reaches-4422.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/powerful-reaches-4422.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/powerful-reaches-4422.git'
```

Also please see my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',        '4.2.2'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.2'
gem 'uglifier',     '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks',   '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',         '0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

And Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
actionmailer (4.2.2)
  actionpack (= 4.2.2)
  actionview (= 4.2.2)
  activejob (= 4.2.2)
  mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
  rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
actionpack (4.2.2)
  actionview (= 4.2.2)
  activesupport (= 4.2.2)
  rack (~> 1.6)
  rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
  rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
  rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
actionview (4.2.2)
  activesupport (= 4.2.2)
  builder (~> 3.1)
  erubis (~> 2.7.0)
  rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
  rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
activejob (4.2.2)
  activesupport (= 4.2.2)
  globalid (>= 0.3.0)
activemodel (4.2.2)
  activesupport (= 4.2.2)
  builder (~> 3.1)
activerecord (4.2.2)
  activemodel (= 4.2.2)
  activesupport (= 4.2.2)
  arel (~> 6.0)
activesupport (4.2.2)
  i18n (~> 0.7)
  json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
  minitest (~> 5.1)
  thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
  tzinfo (~> 1.1)
arel (6.0.3)
binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
  debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
builder (3.2.2)
byebug (8.2.1)
coffee-rails (4.1.1)
  coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
  railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.1.x)
coffee-script (2.4.1)
  coffee-script-source
  execjs
coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
concurrent-ruby (1.0.0)
debug_inspector (0.0.2)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (2.6.0)
globalid (0.3.6)
  activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
i18n (0.7.0)
jbuilder (2.3.2)
  activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
  multi_json (~> 1.2)
jquery-rails (4.0.5)
  rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0)
  railties (>= 4.2.0)
  thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
json (1.8.3)
loofah (2.0.3)
  nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
mail (2.6.3)
  mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
mime-types (2.99)
mini_portile2 (2.0.0)
minitest (5.8.3)
multi_json (1.11.2)
nokogiri (1.6.7.1)
  mini_portile2 (~> 2.0.0.rc2)
rack (1.6.4)
rack-test (0.6.3)
  rack (>= 1.0)
rails (4.2.2)
  actionmailer (= 4.2.2)
  actionpack (= 4.2.2)
  actionview (= 4.2.2)
  activejob (= 4.2.2)
  activemodel (= 4.2.2)
  activerecord (= 4.2.2)
  activesupport (= 4.2.2)
  bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
  railties (= 4.2.2)
  sprockets-rails
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
  activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
  activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
  nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
  rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
  loofah (~> 2.0)
railties (4.2.2)
  actionpack (= 4.2.2)
  activesupport (= 4.2.2)
  rake (>= 0.8.7)
  thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.1)
  json (~> 1.4)
sass (3.4.20)
sass-rails (5.0.4)
  railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
  sass (~> 3.1)
  sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
  sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
  tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
sdoc (0.4.1)
  json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
  rdoc (~> 4.0)
spring (1.6.1)
sprockets (3.5.2)
  concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
  rack (> 1, < 3)
sprockets-rails (3.0.0)
  actionpack (>= 4.0)
  activesupport (>= 4.0)
  sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
sqlite3 (1.3.11)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
tilt (2.0.1)
turbolinks (2.5.3)
  coffee-rails
tzinfo (1.2.2)
  thread_safe (~> 0.1)
uglifier (2.7.2)
  execjs (>= 0.3.0)
  json (>= 1.8.0)
web-console (2.2.1)
  activemodel (>= 4.0)
  binding_of_caller (>= 0.7.2)
  railties (>= 4.0)
  sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  byebug
  coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  rails (= 4.2.2)
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  spring
  sqlite3
  turbolinks
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (~> 2.0)
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Maybe the reason is that the gemfile.lock has sqlite3 as dependency. Can you regenerate it?

Answer (score 1):

Heroku works only with PostgreSQL. You can continue to use **sqlite3** locally, but you need to *switch* to **pg** on Heroku.

```
group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
    end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Then delete

```
`Gemfile.lock`
```

Then run

```
bundle install --without production
```

Do not forget to commit both `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` to the local master before pushing to Heroku.

Comment: Thanks Mihai. I understand about squlite3 and pg, this is reflected in my Gemfile (please see above). I ran the '$ bundle install --without production', then commit. Still getting the same error.

Comment: To commit, I am using `$ git commit -m "x"` , is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's how you commit. Try delete your `Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle install` again.

Comment: **@Mihai-Andrei Dinculescu** Thank you so much . It worked!!! For anyone else having similar problems. I tried a lot of solutions but nothing else worked, I even started over from scratch. This is what worked for me, many thanks to **Mihai-Andrei Dinculescu**.                                                     Delete the Gemfile.lock. Then run `$ bundle install --without production` then you will need to commit this `$ git commit -a -m "Your Message"`. Once this is done, push to Heroku by running `$ git push heroku master`.

Answer (score 0):

did you update your `Gemfile.lock` before pushing? if not to update it `run bundle update`. good luck mate!

Comment: Thanks Marv-c, I ran it, but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the same book! I experienced the same issue. I fixed it by making sure the gems outside the groups in the Gemfile file did not include sqlite3 (above of development and production), sqlite 3 should  only be placed **once** and under the development group. If you tried to deploy you app to heroku it can cause issues. To fix it, make sure sqlite is only listed like:

```
group :development, :test do

 .
 .
gem 'sqlite3'
 .
 .

end
```

and then proceed delete the Gemfile.lock (since a mistake was made, sqlite3 will be listed as a dependency in the Gemfile.lock and it will need to be re-created was deleted by doing a bundle install), next do a bundle install:

```
bundle install --without production
```

(--without production is placed so we don't install locally gems that we wont need) Finish by adding, committing and pushing your changes and then deploying it to heroku. You shouldn't have any issues now.